# Using AWS RDS SQL Server, how can I transfer data from a table to a csv in an s3 bucket, using T_SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, sql-server-2017

Is there a way to transfer the data in a table or data returned from a query, to a csv file in an s3 bucket? We currently backup and restore to s3 and are aware of rds_upload_to_s3 to copy files, but cannot find functionality to make a new file in s3.

Comment: Seems like a task for [AWS Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/data-pipeline/index.html).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes. That's the ticket. Tx.